# Promise not being respected

Tags: ajax, es6-promise, es6-class

I have been banging my head against this for a while now and I can't figure it out.

I have main.js who instantiates a user object and console logs a value from it.

**main.js**

```
jsUser = new user();
console.log(jsUser.passTimes);
```

I then have the user.js file, which houses the class and gets the data for passTimes

**user.js**

```
class user{

    // construct the object
    constructor(obj){

        // just set stuff up, cuz why not?
        this.pTimes = [];

    }

    loadPTimes(){

        // return a promise
        return new Promise((res,rej)=>{

                $.ajax({
                    url: './data/importantfile',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        method: 'getData',
                        termCode: termCode
                    },
                    success: (data)=>{

                        // trigger the resolve
                        res({
                            data: data,
                            class: this
                        });

                    }
                });

        });

    }

    get passTimes(){

        // if pTimes is empty, or gone for some reason, do the following
        if(
            this.pTimes === undefined ||
            this.pTimes.length == 0
        ){
            // go get that promise and do stuff
            this.loadPTimes().then((obj)=>{
                
                // mom always told me I have value, and now I can prove it
                this.pTimes = obj.data;

                // send me up the chain
                return this.pTimes;
            });
        }else{

            // I always had value :), great send me up
            return this.pTimes;
        }

    }
}
```

Easy enough right?  However, when the page actually loads the console.log triggers while the promise/ajax is still running and returns undefined.  Not what I was expecting.

What I was trying to do is, if the get function is triggered and we have no established value; go get the data using ajax and wait for that data to come back before return something.

I have rewritten this so many different ways with different results, but not the result I was looking for (console.log returns the actual ajax results).

I was hoping someone here has used a similar pattern, or a better one.  That waits for data before returning.

**Edited:**

Maybe my questions was written clearly enough.  I need ajax data, when the class is constructed or when the *get* function is called.  It has to be there.

It can't be asynchronous because that data is needed almost immediately. So I throw the request in a promise, expecting the promise to be respected and the *get* function to return when it has data.

This is not happening, instead *get* is returning undefined as a value while the ajax request is still waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem:

```js
class user{

    // construct the object
    constructor(obj){

        // just set stuff up, cuz why not?
        this.pTimes = [];

    }

    loadPTimes(){

        // return a promise
        return new Promise((res,rej)=>{

                $.ajax({
                    url: './data/importantfile',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        method: 'getData',
                        termCode: termCode
                    },
                    success: (data)=>{

                        // trigger the resolve
                        res({
                            data: data,
                            class: this
                        });

                    }
                });

        });

    }

    get passTimes(){
      return (async () => {
      
      // if pTimes is empty, or gone for some reason, do the following
        if(
            this.pTimes === undefined ||
            this.pTimes.length == 0
        ){
            // go get that promise and do stuff
            const obj = await this.loadPTimes();
            // mom always told me I have value, and now I can prove it
            this.pTimes = obj.data;
                // send me up the chain
            return this.pTimes;
           
        }else{
            // I always had value :), great send me up
            return this.pTimes;
        }

      })();
    }
}
```

passTimes will return a promise so to get the value you must use `await` or `then/catch closure`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

- It is impossible to expect to get a result *now*, when it is only available in the *future*. So whatever you do, you must wait with executing logic that needs the response to be available. For this you should execute that logic in a `then` callback, or suspend a function's further execution with `await`.
- Your code creates a `new Promise` when you already have a promise that is returned by `$.ajax` (unless you really use a version of jQuery that is more than a decade old).
- Your code checks the `length` property of the object assigned to `pTimes`, but when you get back the response, you assign a plain object to that property, which has no `length` property. So it is wrong to check that property.

Here is one of the many ways to do what you want:

```
class User { // Common habit to name constructors with PascalCase
    constructor(obj){
        this.pTimes = null; // It wont be an array!
    }
    async loadPTimes() {
        // Don't create a new Promise when you already have one (from $.ajax)
        const data = await $.ajax({
            url: './data/importantfile',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                method: 'getData',
                termCode: termCode
            }
        });
        return this.pTimes = {
            data: data,
            class: this
        };
    }
    get passTimes() {
        return this.pTimes ?? this.loadPTimes();
    }
}

(async () => {
    var jsUser = new User(); // Declare variables with var/let/const!
    console.log(await jsUser.passTimes); // Use await
    // Anything that needs this result, should be coded here, or be called from here.
})(); // Execute the main script inside an async function, so you can use AWAIT
// Don't put any code outside the above wrapper -- except function/class definitions
```